# Finding rational points at rational distance in the plane

Tags: analysis, rational-numbers, real-numbers

Take any point $p$ in the real plane.

Does there always exist a rational point at a rational distance from $p$?

(A **rational point** is a point $(q,r)$ where $q$ and $r$ are rational.)

Comment: No; take the coordinates of $p$ to be transcendental.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Take $p$ to be $(1/\pi, \sqrt{1-1/\pi^2})$.  Aren't both coordinates transcendental?  And isn't $p$ unit distance from the origin?

Comment: Fair enough; transcendental and algebraically independent.

Answer (score 6):

Let our point $P$ be $(\pi, 0)$. If the rational point $(a,b)$ were at a rational distance from $(\pi,0)$, then $\pi$ would be algebraic. But it is not.

**Detail**: If the distance from $(x,0)$ to $(a,b)$ is $r$, then $x^2-2ax +a^2+b^2-r^2=0$. If $a$, $b$, and $r$ are rational, then $x$ is a root of a quadratic equation with rational coefficients. But $\pi$ is not the root of a non-trivial *polynomial* equation with rational coefficients.

A somewhat fancier argument shows that there is also no rational point at a rational distance from $(2^{1/3},0)$.